# Highcharts highstocks - Dual chart axis issue

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, highcharts

Looking through the documentation for Highstocks, I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/):

[image: Example 1]

Shown here is two series on the same chart, therefore with a linked range selector - this is really really useful, but I wish to display something different which is proving to be very difficult.

What I'm looking for is a normal line graph on the top series, representing data plotted onto time (almost like in this example), but a bar chart or horizontal candle chart in the lower graph, representing one or more timelines.

I've drawn an image of what I'm looking for:

[image]

I apologise for the crude drawing, but hopefully it shows what I am aiming to achieve: standard graph on top, bar/candle on bottom.

I have attempted various techniques to render this, but I can't find a way to have both series **drawn on the same timescale, linked with the same range selector.**

In case it helps, here's a starting point on JSFiddle, with all the unnecessary code removed: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/8JhXv/

and a link to the original demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from [official Highcharts forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=19373)

> it is possible, but with some limitations. In the fact you want to show gantt chart. Bar charts aren't possible in your case - bar chart = inverted whole chart (yAxis becames xAxis, etc). Instead take a look at example for gantt chart: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/
>
> You can combine them into one, ane effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8JhXv/1/
>
> About limits:
>
> - tooltip fo bottom chart is availabe only when you mouseover start and end date
> - bars are on lines, not between them

Comment: Thanks for keeping Stack Overflow the central answer-base of all-knowing genius :)

Comment: Was just browsing the Forums and saw the post :) quite a coincidence